# checking from database method

Tags: java, servlets

I have a DBHandler java class which contains multiple methods, this is one of them:

```
public Boolean authenticate(User u) throws SQLException
{
        Boolean f=false;
    // connect to data base
    try {
        connectToDB();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    // retrieve users based on the last name
    Statement s = null;
try {

     String query = "select * from user where email='"+u.getEmail()+"' and password='"+u.getPassword()+"'";

     s = conn.createStatement();

     ResultSet rs= s.executeQuery(query);
      if (rs.next()){//also rs.first() didnt work
         f= true;
     }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        // close both the SQL statement and the DB connection
          if (s != null) {s.close();}
          if (conn != null){conn.close();}
         }
    return f;
}
```

This method checks if the user exists in the database and returns a Boolean value.

I'm calling this method in a servlet and print the returned value like this:

```
       User users= new User();
        users.name="lamatat";
        users.email="lamatata@hotmail.com";
        users.password="1234567890";
        users.id=3;
        DBHandler db= new DBHandler();
        Boolean b=db.authenticate(users);
        out.println("<h1>Servlet Login at " + b + "</h1>");
```

But this always return true even when its false...

I don't know what or where the error is?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`rs.equals("")` - a `ResultSet` most probably will *never* be equal to a `String`, hence `f = false` won't be called here. Use `f = rs.next()` instead, as already stated by others.

Basically you'd do:

```
ResultSet rs= s.executeQuery(query);
boolean f = rs.next(); //if true, the query found a matching user
```

Besides that, you should not assume the user is authenticated at the start (`Boolean f=true;`) but assume he's not authenticated only change the flag in case of authentication success. That way when you have a bug you won't get accidentially authenticated users. In most cases it's better to deny access in case of a bug instead of granting it.

Another hint on security: you should store hashed passwords (preferably salted as well) in the database and create a hash for the plain password entered by the user and use this hash in the query.

**Update**: Rereading your query there's another potential security issue. If you add query parameters to the query string like in `"... where email='"+u.getEmail()+"' ..."` you are vulnerable to SQL injection, i.e. an attacker could use the "email" `crap' or true; --`, which would result in this query string:

```
 select * from user where email='crap' or true;-- and password='whatever'
```

An attacker could thus hack his way into the system, since the query would always return something.
The same is true for the password, at least unless it is hashed.

Thus you'd better use `PreparedStatement` here.

Comment: tried it but didn't work too.. always return true.. thanks for the security hint im going to do it after i solve this..

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the actual record, try this:

```
ResultSet rs= s.executeQuery(query);
f = rs.next();// true, if record exist else false
```

In your case, your verifying whether `rs` object is equal to `""` blank string or not and that wrong your suppose to verify the data.

**EDIT**

The above changes are for `authenticate()`, replace the below code with above said code

```
ResultSet rs= s.executeQuery(query);
  if (rs.first()){
     f= true;
 }
```

P.S. use `PreparedStatement` in-case of runtime parameters for sql queries.

Comment: wher to put f=rs.next() ?

Comment: @DARKHORSE, any exceptions?

Comment: no but always return true .. can you check my post i edited it

Comment: @DARKHORSE, kindly see my post, use `f = rs.next();`

Comment: @DARKHORSE, what is the datatype of email id and password column? make sure its varchar else you might be getting extra spaces from db, spaces are major issues in this kind of scenario

Comment: the email and password are varchar but the id is int but its not used in this method .. and i didnt get what you mean by extra space from db .. can you explain it please ?

Comment: @DARKHORSE, kindly run the same query and verify the existence of the record from the db first.

Comment: i did and i got the result i want

Answer (score 0):

According to your code and the command you are executing on Database if you check `rs.next();` you can get if there is a user like you are passing. like this:

```
if (rs.next()){
             f= true;
         }
```

Comment: how and where i use re.next() ?

Comment: same :( .. can you check my post i edited to yours .. maybe im missing something

Comment: You're very welcome bro, what about trying **if (rs.getString("email")==u.getEmail())**

Comment: so probably you are Testing for an existing user; I have no more Idea hope your problem solve soon